# Transaction management in EJB 3.0 and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0

I am trying to understand the transactions management and try to use its power in my already existing application developed in Struts 2, EJB 3 and hibernate 5.2.
Now I have ejb in my business layer like below

```
   @Stateless
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
    public class MyEJb implements ejbxyz {

    @Override
    public void method(){
          Dao dao=new Dao() //Dao class is simple java class
          dao.fooMethod();  //this method updates some record
          dao.barMethod();  // this method updates some other record
        }
    } 

    public class Dao{
         fooMethid(){
         Session session=sessFactory.openSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
         session.update(x);
              }
         barMethod(){
              try{
                   Session session=sessFactory.getCurrentSession();
                    session.getNamedQuery("xyz").executeUpdate();

                }catch(HibernateException ex){
                    session.getTransaction.rollback();
                } 
             }
           }
```

I understand that Transaction management should be done at service layer(at ejb in my case). But how can I achieve this over there. ?

Now the dependency is if barMethod() fails to update the record then I need to rollback the changes made in fooMethod. So basically I need both the methods to be done in one transaction.
When I execute the application it throws the below exception

```
Exception while barMethod getNamedQuery is not valid without active transaction
```

Its because I am not beginning any transaction in barMethod. But then I really dont want to start a new transaction and want to continue with the older transaction started in fooMethod.

Comment: As you said: *transaction management should be done at service layer*. And it is, since you're using a stateless EJB, which starts and commit transactions for you. So don't deal with transactions in the DAO methods. The transactions are handled, for you, automatically, by the EJB container. And also, don't use the proprietry Hibernate API. Use JPA.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please elaborate on "don't use the proprietry Hibernate API. Use JPA". isn't hibernate a JPA implementation ?

Comment: Java EE has a standard specification named JPA. It defines standard interfaces (EntityManager...), methods, annotations. Hibernate is an implementation of JPA. You should use the standard API rather than the proprietary Hibernate Session API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container managed transactions are indeed suported out of the box for EJB beans. However, your `Dao` class is not a managed bean - it is a regular pojo that you instantiate manualy - therefore it does not participate in any transaction started by your other ejb.
So move your `Dao` to separate file, annotate it with `@Stateless` and then inject it into your service using `@EJB private Dao dao;`
There is more to transactions in Ejb container though. You can control the transaction support on method level via `@TransactionAttribute` annotation, that specifies how should the container invoke your method with regard to transaction. That way you can control, whether your method requires its own transaction, or  if it shall participate in a transaction initiated by the caller(e.g. when invoked from ejb bean).  For more info have a look at official [Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions003.htm)

Comment: Okay. But don't you think that marking dao as ejb will increase the overhead of the container ? I am just curious.

Comment: Not really, right now your Dao is hirdwired to your `MyEjb` which is pooled, so for every instance of MyEjb there is one instance of Dao. If you turn the Dao into dedicated bean, it will have its own pool and will be injected into MyEjb. The overhead of single managed bean is negligible and your server can happily serve hundreds of beans. Focus on your business logic and let the server do its job, it is likely that you will not need any performance tuning at all;)